# Release plan using jenkins, Git and maven

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket, release-management

Currently, I am trying to automate a pipeline for our team using Jenkins, Git and maven. The constraint we have is that Jenkins has read-only access to Git. We have a master branch as our mainstream and a 'release; branch which -as the name implies- used only for releases.

I am trying to achieve the following:
Whenever developer merges master into release, 2 things should happen:
1- Create a tag and remove the -SNAPSHOT on the release branch.
2- Increase the version number in POM and create a snapshot.

Any ideas how can I achieve this while I am not able to push from Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Even if Jenkins does not have write permission to your GIT you can do below things.

```
1. Create Trigger Job in Jenkins on release branch (whenever a change is pushed to release branch) , call it Job A.
2. Job A will ssh into some system which has write permission to GIT , make necessary changes , create a war file (mvn should be installed).
3. Push war/jar to some location and deploy.
```

Hope this helps.:)